# Group sequential repeated values sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have data that repeated sequentially..

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
A
A
A
```

I need to group them like this

```
A
B
A
```

What is the best approach to do so using sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a column that defines the ordering of the rows, say `id`, you can address this gaps-and-island problem with window functions:

```
select col, count(*) cnt, min(id) first_id, max(id) last_id
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(order by id) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by col order by id) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by col, rn1 - rn2
order by min(id)
```

I added a few columns to the resultset that give more information about the content of each group.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a column that defines the order of the rows, like an `id`, you can use window function `LEAD()`:

```
select col
from (
  select col, lead(col, 1, '') over (order by id) next_col
  from tablename
)
where col <> next_col
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g7drNeDmmdvcUiMdQwSwLf/0).
Results:

```
| col |
| --- |
| A   |
| B   |
| A   |
```